# Access Context API in a standalone JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I would like to access a variable inside my global state using the React Context API in little module that I'm importing. This is my module:

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
  params: {
    user_id: 0
  }
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

How would I go about accessing a specific variable inside my global state in a file like this? I would like to set the user_id in this example.
Do I need to wrap the following variable instance in a React Component which is wrapped by a Consumer? or is there another way?

I'm having trouble finding documentation covering this topic. In all the examples I found the context is passed through in the render method of a React component.

Comment: if your `user_id` is always changing, you should not set that in the instance. Instead, do it in the api call. if it is not changing, just set it in ENV file ?

Comment: it's being set depending on a query parameter on page load